# What is the difference between map and doOnNext in flux? (i.e project reactor)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive

In Flux `map` function is also executed for each item in the flux. For `doOnNext` function is also executed for every item (emitted) in the flux. What is the difference from the user's perspective? Why do two similar methods exist? Could someone explain with a simple use-case?

Answer (score 18):

TLDR;
`Flux#doOnNext` is for side effects,
`Flux#map` is for mapping something from one type to another type, synchronously.

If we look at the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) it says the following for `doOnNext`

```
Flux<T> doOnNext(Consumer<? super T> onNext)
Add behavior (side-effect) triggered when the Flux emits an item.
```

this means in `doOnNext`, we can do side effects, like log, or do a rest call somewhere etc. etc. We also return a Flux of type `T`, that is the same that `doOnNext` is taking in, so no type change.

If we on the other hand look at `Map`:

```
Flux<V> map(Function<? super T,? extends V> mapper)
Transform the items emitted by this Flux by applying a synchronous function to 
each item.
```

We can read that here we can apply a synchronous function, basically we can do something with our emitted value. Add something, deduct something, change it some way, here we can transform it, for instance `map` it to something else.

If we look at the types in `map`, we can see that `map` will emit something `super T` but it will return something that `extends V`

This is a typical Java generics pattern and if you wish to know more about just this, I recommend you watch [Joshua Blochs talk about generics](https://youtu.be/V1vQf4qyMXg?t=1324). The entire video is a good watch and will explain it much better than me.

But what I want to point out is that by using `map`, you are returning a **different** type. You get something that `super T` from the flux, you then map it to something else that `extends V`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The map function can do  "what doOnNext function can do".  what i s the functionality doOnNext function can do, the map function can't do?

Comment: it does not consume the items, map function does

Comment: IMO, doOnNext provides immutability of the received input. In `map` you don't.

Answer (score 18):

Just to add to the [other nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60105107/13349505) - I think the one important part that I was missing when I started using `doOnNext()` is that it is not a "consumer" counter-part of "function-like" `map` and `flatMap`.

`doOnNext` is sort of a callback that gets executed when a Publisher emits an item but it does not affect the flow, namely it returns the original Publisher **immediately**.
Example: initially I thought I could do things like

```
Mono.from()
    .doOnNext(doSomethingConsumer)
    .doOnNext(thenDoSomethingElseConsumer);
```

when I am not interested in the return value and that these things will be applied in order.
This is completely wrong! In fact, both `doOnNext()` operators are applied immediately.

Comment: What was the correct way to do what you wanted?

Comment: I tried running 2 doOnNext. 1 with a sleep, the two didn't get executed parallely. 2nd doOnNext waited for completion of the 1st doOnNext. So they are kind of applied in order? https://gist.github.com/asthinasthi/5d3cc12e853449063a0e0a724e704b4a