# Extract Mono nonblocking response and store it in a variable and use it globally

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, webclient, webflux

In my project I have a requirement where I need to call a third party api authentic url to get the the access token. I need to set that access token in every subsequent request header .The access token has some lifetime and when the lifetime expired I need to regenerate the access token.

**`application.yml`**
I have hardcoded the client_id,client_secret,auth_url and grant_type .

**`AuthController.java`**
here I have created an endpoint to generate the access token.

```
**`AuthService.java`**
@Services
@Slf4j
public class AuthService{
 @Autowired
 private WebClient webClient;
static String accessToken="";
public Mono<SeekResponse> getAccessToken(AuthRequest authRequest) throws InvalidTokenException{
  Mono<AuthResponse> authResponse=webClient.post()
                  .bodyValue(authRequest)
                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                  .retrive()
                  .bodyToMono(AuthResponse.class);

 authResponse.doOnNext(response->{
       String value=response.getAccess_token();
       accessToken=accessToken+value; 
  })
}
}
```

Although I have updated the "accessToken" value but it will return me null. I understand as I have made async call this value coming as null. I can't use blocking mechanism here.
Is there any other way to generate the access token and pass it as a header for the subsequent request for authentication. Or how can I use the accessToken value globally so that I can set those token value to my subsequent api request call.

I have tried with oAuth2 by following the below article:
https://medium.com/@asce4s/oauth2-with-spring-webclient-761d16f89cdd
But when I execute I am getting the below error :
"An expected CSRF token cannot found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also learning Webflux. Here's my thought. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

We are not going to rely on `doOnNext()` nor `doOnSuccess()` nor other similar method to try to work on an pre-defined variable `accessToken` (That's not a way to let Mono flow). What we should focus on is converting a mono to another mono, for example converting mono response to mono access token.

The way to do that is `.flatmap()`/`.map()`/`.zipwith()`/...
For example,

```
Mono<string> tokenMono = responseMono.flatmap(
    // in the map or flatmap, we get the chance to operate on  variables/objects.
    resp -> { 
        string token = response.getAccess_token();
        return Mono.just(token); // with Mono.just(), we are able to convert object to Mono again.
    }
) // this example is not practical, as map() is better to do the same thing. flatmap with Mono.just() is meaningless here.

Mono<string> tokenMono2 = responseMono.map(
        resp -> { 
            string token = response.getAccess_token();
            return token;
        }
    )
```

Everything starting from Mono should be always Mono until subscribed or blocked. And they provide us ways to operate on those `variables` inside `Mono<variables>`. Those are `map()` `flatmap()`, `zipwith()`, etc.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60105107/18412317
Referring to a point this author said, `doOnNext()` is for side effect such as logging.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand provided sample and implementation is not really reactive. The method returns `Mono` but at the same time `throws InvalidTokenException` or usage of `onNext` that is a so-called side-effect operation that should be used for logging, metrics, or other similar use cases.

The way you implement oauth flow for WebClient is to create `filter`, [Client Filters](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux-client/webflux-client-filter.html).

Spring Security provides some boilerplates for common oauth flows. Check [Spring Security OAuth2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html) for more details.

Here is an example of simple implementation of the client credential provider

```
private ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth(String clientRegistrationId, ClientConfig config) {
    var clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId)
            .tokenUri(config.getAuthUrl() + "/token")
            .clientId(config.getClientId())
            .clientSecret(config.getClientSecret())
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .build();

    var authRepository = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
    var authClientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(authRepository);

    var authClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            authRepository, authClientService);

    var oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authClientManager);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId);
    return oauth;
}
```

then you could use it in the `WebClient`

```
WebClient.builder()
    .filter(oauth)
    .build()
```

**UPDATE**
Here is an example of the alternative method without filters

**AuthService**

```
@Service
public class AuthService {
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public AuthService() {
        this.webClient = WebClient.create("<url>/token");
    }

    public Mono<String> getAccessToken() {
        return webClient.post()
                .bodyValue()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(AuthResponse.class)
                .map(res -> res.getAccessToken());
    }
}
```

**ApiService**

```
@Service
public class ApiService {
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final Mono<String> requestToken;

    public ApiService(AuthService authService) {
        this.webClient = WebClient.create("<url>/api");
        // cache for token expiration
        this.requestToken = authService.getAccessToken().cache(Duration.ofMinutes(10));
    }

    public Mono<String> request() {
        return requestToken
                .flatMap(token ->
                        webClient.get()
                                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token)
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .retrieve()
                                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: If we are not doing any oAuth2.0 approach instead calling the the 3rd party authetication url and getting the access token and use it for subsequent request. Is it a good approach?

Comment: I want to store the access token as global variable and then will reuse that for subsequent request. But with the reactive approach it is not allowing me.

Comment: I would still recommend using filter but as an alternative approach you could store token `Mono` in the class field like `Mono<String> accessToken = getAccessToken().cache()` and then use it in the request `accessToken.flatMap(token -> request(token))`. This way accessToken `Mono` would be resolved only once (assuming token has no expiration). You could also cache it for a limited time using `cache(Duration.ofMinutes(10))` to update token every X minutes.

Comment: When other request needs that access token how that can be accessed/

Comment: Can you please share some reference ?Suppose in AuthService.java , I have cached the access token ,Mono<String> accessToken=authResponse.map(token->token.getAccess_token)).cache(Duration.ofMinutes(10));. Now, I have different service class in which I need to fetch userDetails by setting the token value in header.In this situation how will my other service class retrieve the value from cache.

Comment: does this line means I need to create a method which contains token as parameter.accessToken.flatMap(token -> request(token))

Comment: I would rather inject AuthService into the class that makes a request and initialize  `Mono<String> accessToken = getAccessToken().cache()` in the constructor. You could also encapsulate this in the  AuthService and return cached `Mono`. But the key here is that `getAccessToken()` is async and you need to construct reactive flow

Comment: Thing is that from Mono I need to extract the token and set it into cache as a string. Within Mono it is fine I can extract it as a String but outside of Mono token is coming as null.

Comment: @stumbler updated the answer and added one more example based on comments

Comment: I can now access the token as a static variable . In service class where I need to set the token as header I have checked if token has empty or not .If empty I am calling my AuthService to generate the token and then save it in a static variable. authService.getAccessToken(authRequest).flatMap(response->accessToken=response.getAccessToken();

Comment: But now I want to set in Cache with expiry time.